# how to implement Twitter authentication in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, twitter-oauth, aws-amplify

so I created an app with AWS Amplify by running `amplify init` and, following the steps, I was able to configure Facebook and Google as authentication providers really easily as they are supported as Federated Providers in Cognito. However I have no idea how am I supposed to implement authentication with Twitter and make it work with Cognito the same way the Facebook/Google authenticating works since it is using a custom OAuth v1 flow.

Has anyone done it, and if so, what resources could you recommend me? I saw there are some tutorials to integrate Auth0 with Cognito and I know Auth0 supports Twitter login however they have some limitations for active users etc. so I would really appreciate it if we can handle that ourselves without having to rely on yet another provider.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Twitter now supports OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect was built on top of OAuth 2.0. I was thinking to use twitter as an OpenID Connect in Cognito.

Comment: I went with a custom back end where I can implement whatever login I need

Answer (score 5):

Just spoke with AWS Support and confirmed that they removed Twitter as an option. :(